# pass helper url as unencoded to link_to url:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to create a link using one of my helper paths like so:

```
<%= link_to url: admin_url(group) do %><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><% end %>
```

but it seems when rails renders the page, the elements looks like:

```
<a href="/admin?url=%2Fadmin%2F1%2Fedit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
```

how do I properly link to `admin_url(group)` ?

Comment: why are you passing the `url` parameter? I would expect that to be used like this: `link_to admin_path(group)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= link_to admin_url(group) do %><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><% end %>
```

Passing a hash as the first argument is only done if you are using [polymorphic routing](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html) instead of a route helper or literal path:

```
link_to(action: 'foo', controller: 'bar') do
  # name
end
```

> Missing routes keys may be filled in from the current request's parameters (e.g. :controller, :action, :id and any other parameters that are placed in the path)

Which gives us `/admin`

`url_for` will then slurp up any non-reserved options like `url` and add them to the query string which is why you get `/admin?url=%2Fadmin%2F1%2Fedit"`.